# How can i run Universal Windows Platform desktop app on android mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, winjs

I have been Implemented Universal Windows Platform  app in visual studio using winJS, javascript,css and html now i want to use same code base for creating android application..so what all things i need to do to run desktop application into my android mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a new hybrid application for android using Xamrain as for you can reuse the logic but to port, The whole UWP Application to android using the same is not possible as the scenario you are mentioning.

Comment: It isn't, The only option you could have right now is the hybrid application. You could follow any framework you like. But I think you could give a shot with Ionic or React native as you can very much use the javascript HTML stuff in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of your winjs and html code for a hybrid Cordova app (cross-platform)

See here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/23/apache-cordova-and-winjs/